# RestApi Design Pros/Cons

Tags: rest

Lets say I have a simple API

`api/users`

Which returns an array of users, or an empty array if there are none.

I want to be able to find users by id and name, so I've done some possible ways of doing that:

`api/users/1` or `api/users?id=1`

or by name

`api/users/john` or `api/users?name=John`

In this second case, searching by name, should I return a 404 or a empty array when john was not found? Is this a good design practice I'm taking?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question targets URI design but not REST. REST is an architectural style which if followed correctly is used to decouple clients from servers by relying on a intermediary media type both client and servers understand. Servers will provide URIs clients can use, though how this URI is set up (logical order, semantical meaning of segments, ...) is not of relevance to the client as is should not try to extract meaning from URI but just invoke it. The semantics of the URI should be transported via relation names instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about *URL design* and not about *REST*.

You could consider the following:

- `GET /api/users/{id}`: Returns a representation of the user with the given identifier. If no users match the given identifier, a `404` response should be returned.
- `GET /api/users?name={name}`: Returns a representation of a collection with the users that match the given name. If no users match the given name, a `200` response with an empty array should be returned.

Comment: @GabrielSlomka Then you could support both locators for the same resource. Consider a user `johnsnow` with the id `1`. You can have the following URIs: `/api/users/1` and `/api/users/johnsnow`. Some frameworks support regular expressions to match path parameters.